# Should LoggingInterceptors be static in CXF?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I have several `CXF`-interceptors that I currently just recreate using `new` operator on each soap webservice request.

I wonder if I should make these interceptors static?

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
LoggingOutInterceptor loi = new MyLoggingOutInterceptor(); //static??
loi.setPrettyLogging(true);
loi.setPrettyLogging(true);
client.getInInterceptors().add(loi);
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking to make them single instances within your code base. So singletons might be better. Or if you're using Spring, there's a whole realm of [CXF Interceptor Bus Spring Integration](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/bus-configuration.html) that you can discover.

Comment: I'm just creating a soap client. So I can conclude that a static/singleton interceptor is the right aproach, and way better than constantly recreating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if a client proxy is shared among threads ([subject to these restrictions](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAX-WSclientproxiesthreadsafe?)), you should be OK using a single instance of logging interceptor provided it's implementation is also thread-safe.